# How do I update this google captcha from version 2 to the latest version 3 on my site. I am using Gravity forms and I have this site built on wp

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, gravityforms

I have already done google search about this topic but did not get any specific suggestion on how can I update from google recaptcha version 2 to the latest version on this wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you want to do is Install this fantastic plugin for Recaptcha V3.

Simple go to your plugins, Add plugins, then look for: Invisible reCaptcha for WordPress.

Once you've installed it, on your wordpress sidebar, this will appear as a settings option, so hover over settings & click on Invisible reCaptcha.

The first thing you'll see is to enter your Site & Security key from signing up to use V3.

You can also choose the position of the badge & Language.

Then when you've entered the keys and you're happy with the position of the badge, go to the left had options on the plugin, and you'll need to go down to "Contact forms" and tick the Gravity forms protection tick box.

After saving, wait a little bit, clear your cache, and you should see the google badge appearing on the front-end of your website.

Hope this helps :)

Edit: Remember to remove your V2 Captcha fields off your forms, or this will give you some horrible errors!